# GCM click_action property on payload is not appearing

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use the click_action property on iOS which is like category for them, but the payload doesn't send the click_action option inside. and really weird

```
$payLoad['notification'] = [
            'title' => $push->getTitle(),
            'text'  => $push->getAlert(),
            'badge' => 1,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'click_action' => $push->getClickAction()
        ];
```

Is there something about it? or maybe if will be an option to send it in the custom-data?

Comment: Is the `$push->getClickAction()` a string? The [Notification payload support](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) section of the documentation indicates that it needs to be a string for it to work. You'll have to use the value that you would use for `category` in APNs payload.

Comment: Yes it is, I even harcoded the value but nothing changes